# MySQL - remove whitespace before and after a given string or char

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update a row by removing the whitespace (1 or more spaces) before and after a given string or char? I need all spaces before and after a specific char (@) to be stripped but also leave the other spaces in the cell intact.

Example:

```
'This is a simple     @ example'
```

should be updated to

```
'This is a simple@example'
```

likewise:

```
'This is another  @example'
```

should be updated to

```
'This is another@example'
```

I can do this using PHP but it would be much easier if there was a way to have this done in a single query.

Comment: `replace(replace(yourfield, ' @', '@'), '@ ', '@')`. keep running that until you get no more replacements.

Comment: @MarcB Make it an answer.

Comment: Replace will do as @MarcB mentioned

Comment: I've edited my question to make the examples more clear about conditions with multiple spaces.

Comment: Really, all you need to do is `REPLACE` the white spaces with empties.

Comment: If I replace ALL spaces then the result will be 'Thisisasimple@xample', not what I need.

Comment: Run it several times and it's gone... don't overkill it. It will only replace spaces around the `@` symbol until it cannot find any

Comment: Please explain 'several times'... You mean the entire query or just the replace part? Not very keen on this solution even if does the job.

Comment: did Nanne's or my solution help you?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(line, ' @', '@'), '@ ', '@') FROM tab1;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7639f/2/0)

UPDATE:

to allow for the removal of any number of spaces before or after the @ do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(RTRIM(LEFT(line,LOCATE('@',line)-1)),'@',
       LTRIM(SUBSTR(line,LOCATE('@',line)+1)))
FROM tab1;
```

see the new [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fb9df/7/0) to play around with this.

Note that if you have more than one @ in the line this method only works for the first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default regex you can use with replacing. So the options you have are:

1. **extend MySQL with a regex-replace:**
   You could use a UDF (user defined function, [this one to be exact](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)) to do a regex replace. You can then use something like `\s*@\s*` to indicate multiple spaces around an `@`.
2. **Use the default replace:** 
   you'd need to 'hardcode' your replaces to account for several spaces before and after the `@`, a cumbersome (and never complete) task. You'd end up with a lot of replaces, or a repetition of a certain function (remove 100 times one space from the `@` sign). To be clear, the mentioned doubble replace in the comments and @luksch' answer will not suffice for more then 1 space.

Comment: 3. split the sting at the @ and use ```LTRIM``` and ```RTRIM```. see my answer update :) The drawback with UDF is that you need to create these on each mysql instance you want to run the query on. If that is no problem, then your solution 1 is perfect.